# Displaying MySQL datetime in JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, datetime, date

In a MySQL db I have ta table which contains a datetime column, which has the format '2012-01-18 09:45:30'. I query the contents of this table using the following syntax:

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.executeQuery( "select * from db_name.tbl_name;");
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
ResultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();

//Put Column Header info in Vector
Vector columnNames = new Vector();
for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
    columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnLabel(column+1));
}

//Put sql table data in Vector of Vectors
Vector data = new Vector();
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector newRow = new Vector();
    newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
}
s.close();
rs.close();
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

If I do not override the getColumnClass in the DefaultTableModel then the MySQL datetime column displays in the JTable as a String in the following format:

```
2012-01-18 09:45:30
```

If I get the class name for the datetime column using the following syntax, the class returned is java.sql.Timestamp

```
System.out.println(metaData.getColumnClassName(i));
```

Now, this is the part that confuses me. If I override the getColumnClass method in DefaultTableModel to return the correct class, using the following syntax, then the datetime column is formatted and displayed like this:

```
Jan 18,2012
```

Notice that the time portion is completely omitted.

```
@override
public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
        Object o = getValueAt(row, column);
        if (o != null) {
            try {
                switch (metaData.getColumnClassName(column+1)) {
                    case "java.sql.Timestamp":
                        return java.sql.Timestamp.class;
                    case "java.sql.Date":
                        return java.sql.Date.class;
                } 
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ResultSetToCheckBoxTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    return Object.class;
}
```

Also, if I try to display a java.sql.Date column, it displays as a String with the following format:

```
2012-01-18
```

regardless of whether I override GetColumnClass to return the correct class.

How to display `java.sql.Date` as: `Jan 18, 2012` and `java.sql.TimeStamp` so that it displays the date and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a `TableCellRenderer` for both classes which format the `Timestamp`/`Date` instances exactly as you like. Take a look at the [Swing table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), and in particular to the ['Concepts: Editors and renderers'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and the ['Using custom renderers'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) sections

Answer (score 1):

You could override `DefaultTableModel.getValueAt()` instead and do something like:

```
private static DateFormat dateFormatter =
    DateFormat.getDateInstance();
private static DateFormat timestampFormatter =
    DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();            

...

public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    Object value = super.getValueAt(row, column);
    if (value instanceof Date) {
        synchronized (dateFormatter) {
            dateFormatter.format((Date)value);
        }
    }
    else if (value instanceof Timestamp) {
        synchronized (timestampFormatter) {
            timestampFormatter.format((Date)value);            
        }
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, part of the reason I am overriding the getColumnClass is to force one column to return boolean. I do this to help me add a column of checkboxes and a select/delselect all button on my JTable.